# jQuery star rating question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a around 8 jQuery star rating in my page:

```
<input class= "auto-submit-star" name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
<input class= "auto-submit-star" name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
<input class= "auto-submit-star" name="star2" type="radio" class="star" checked="checked"/>
<input class= "auto-submit-star" name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
<input class= "auto-submit-star" name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
```

What I want to do is that when a user clicks on the rating, it does a post back to the database (MySQL) and update some data. I know there is a callback function for this star rating that looks something like this:

```
$('.auto-submit-star').rating({
    callback: function(value, link){
        $.post("ajax.php", {name: unknown, val: value});
    }
})
```

The question is that in this callback function, how do I get the name. Which is star2 in the example above? Can someone also give me an example of a doing a post

;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an attribute of the clicked element you want to use the `.attr(string)` function.

```
$('.auto-submit-star').rating({
    callback: function(value, link){
        $.post("ajax.php", {name: unknown, val: $(this).attr('name')});
    }
})
```

EDIT: I didn't realize the value was provided as a callback param.

Comment: actually that value argument, should give you the value right? because inside the callback function, when I do an alert(value) it prints out the value

Comment: @aherlambang: yes, if you need the name, have you tried just using `name`?

Comment: so name: name? do I need to put name inside the parameter? so it's function(value, name, link)

Comment: @aherlambang: You would have to change the spec of the rating plugin to alter the number of params the callback function takes.  So no you shouldn't need to add the param to the callback, just use the code above to grab the name attribute or make the value of the radio buttons equal to the name and use the built in functionality of the plugin.